# Given a $M(x)$= definite integral of $ f(t)dt$, determine$ f$ and the constant knowing that is continuous

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

## Considering the function

$$M(x)= \int_{4}^{x^2}f(t)dt=e^{2x^2}+ x^4+8x^2+k$$

determine f and k knowing that f is continuous on ℝ.

#### My steps(not sure if are right)

#### For get f:

derivate $e^{2x^2}+ x^4+8x^2+k$ and get $2xe^{2x^2}+ 4x^3+16x$

#### for get k:

$M(4)=0$ (becouse the definite integral of lenght =0),so replacing in $M(x)$
I get $e^{32} +384=-k$

So my solution would be $k=-e^{32} -384$ and $f=2xe^{2x^2}+ 4x^3+16x$ but the result of $k$ seems a bit strange, so, is right the procedure?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeking the function $f$ and constant $k$ of
\begin{align}
M(x) = \int_{4}^{x^{2}} f(t) \, dt = e^{2 x^{2}} + x^{4} + 8x^{2} + k
\end{align}
is as follows. When $x=2$ the integral is of zero value which yields
\begin{align}
M(2) = 0 = e^{8} + 48 + k
\end{align}
or $k = - e^{8} - 48$. Now differentiation of $M(x)$ follows from Leibnitz's rule,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule, and is
\begin{align}
\partial_{x} M(x) = 2x f(x^{2}) = 4 x e^{2x^{2}} + 4 x^{3} + 16 x
\end{align}
which provides $f(t) = 2 e^{2t} + 2 t + 8$. This can now be stated as
\begin{align}
M(x) = \int_{4}^{x^{2}} \left[ 2 e^{2t} + 2 t + 8 \right] \, dt = e^{2 x^{2}} + x^{4} + 8x^{2} - e^{8} - 48.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Because of the fundamental theorem of calculus the function $F(x)=\int_4^x f(t)dt$ satisfies $F'(x)=f(x)$ (assuming $f$ continuous). You have $M(x)=F(x^2).$ So

$$M'(x)=2x F'(x^2)= 2x f(x^2)\Rightarrow f(x^2)=\frac{M'(x)}{2x}=2e^{2x^2}+2x^2+8.$$ That is,

$f(x)=2e^{2x}+2x+8$ for any $x\geq 0.$

Finally, $M(2)=0$ gives you the value of $k.$